# PHP echo value from a JSON array

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I would like to localize my website so I'm making a JSON array containing variables for 3 different languages, like this:

```
{
    "i18n_en":
    [
        "good"
    ],
    "i18n_de":
    [
        "gut"
    ],
    "i18n_ru":
    [
        "хорошо"
    ]
}
```

And so on... Obviously there's more words in there - and that's how I'm trying to use this in PHP:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('/lang/i18n_en.json', true);
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj[0]["good"];
?>
```

The above code echoes nothing. How can I echo a `specific` item from a `specific` JSON array using php? Something like:

**For example I would like to echo the value of the key "`good`" from the `118n_de` array on one page and echo the same key's value from the `i18n_ru` array on another one.** I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Use json_decode to decode the JSON and make it usable.

Comment: I edited the code in my question. But I get the following error in PHP: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'good' in json.php`

Comment: *Needed, since I also have to (...)* No. Bad way. If your JSON is valid, json_decode strip slashes for you. Otherwise, [check if your JSON is valid](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: @JohnyP.Use json_decode, not stripslashes. Then, use something like print_r to see the actual structure of the resulting object. It may be that $obj is actually an object, not an array.

Comment: not `$obj[0]["good"]` (`$obj` is a string). try with `$json[0]->good`

Comment: @kainaw my json code is similar to the one in the question, but there are more objects in those arrays. fusion3k just found out there's an error, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: If it is similar, it is **NOT VALID**. With not valid JSON, you can not obtain valid array/object.

Comment: I edited my question's JSON so that it is valid. What PHP code to use to echo the first index of the array?